# Anchor link unable to be clicked in parallax enabled page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using Zurb foundation's Manifesto theme for parallax scrolling landing page. Obviously anchor tag is used for scrolling purpose here, therefore when normal anchor link is included in this page, the default function of anchor link is disabled.

HTML for parallax anchor tags (scrolling)

```
<li class="bullet"><a href="#">Fin<span data-width="27"><?php echo $a[1];?></span></a></li>
```

HTML for normal anchor tag included in the header, which is not working

```
<a href="<?php echo URL; ?>dashboard">Dashboard</a>
```

**How to enable normal anchor tag to be clickable while parallax anchor tag to do the relevant function.**

Comment: Care to provide a link to the page in question?

Comment: @jarmerson, I did it in localhost. Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b1thtL33/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these classes to your anchor tag: "button wht manifesto-btn"

```
<a href="<?php echo URL; ?>dashboard" class="button wht manifesto-btn">Dashboard</a>
```

I am not sure it will work. I just checked on the [theme demo page](http://zurb.com/manifesto) that links are working fine when these classes are added to them.

Comment: thanks a lot..it works like a charm..only css changed for the link